# API server and cache problems in nodejs server

Tags: node.js, guzzle

I am building an API Server in node.js. I am doing requests from webapp (using guzzle) which is on different server to my api server. It is working ok. But at some times I get cached results from the api server. Also when sometimes there is 500 error response from api server. Those results are cached. how should I avoid such situations in my api server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply had to pass some headers in middleware

```
function setHeaders(req, res, next) {
    res.set({
      'cache-control': 'max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
      'expires': 0,
      'pragma': 'no-cache'
    });
}
app.use(setHeaders);
```

Answer (score -2):

generate a random number and append with the request url everytime you request.

Comment: Should i instead use response headers from api server?